# Access-Control-Allow-Origin and security behind it

Tags: access-control, api, spoofing

I have some troubles to understand how the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" can really be secure. Let me explain what I have in mind:

Let's say I have an API on `api.contoso.com` setting this header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://contoso.com`
The goal is to allow only calls to this API from `https://contoso.com`.
It means that if I try to call this API from `http://foo.bar`, it'll fail.  (I hope I'm right on this part :p)

But an attacker can create a proxy on its own server, let's take this simple nodejs call:

```
https.request({
    hostname: 'api.contoso.com',
    path: '/my-path',
    method: 'GET',
}).end();
```

And that's it. If I am not wrong, the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` won't be taken into account in that case. And even so, the attacker can simply set the referer in its request options, right?

```
https.request({
    hostname: 'api.contoso.com',
    path: '/my-path',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { Referer: 'https://contoso.com' },
}).end()
```

My point is: if we can get around the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" by making the request on server-side instead of client-side, what's the point of this header? What I miss? ^^'

Thanks in advance for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal of CORS is not to prevent any kind of cross-origin access. Some cross-origin access is possible anyway, like with cross-origin loading of images, submitting of forms etc. What CORS instead tries to prevent is (among some other things) cross-origin access which hijacks an established authenticated session.

While the attacker can create a proxy like you propose it will not have access to the credentials and (session) cookies for `api.contoso.com` which are stored in the browser. These are bound to the target domain. In your case on using a proxy at the attackers site the target domain is the attackers site and not the original site. This means that the proxy might access the target URL but not access it as the authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
Let's say `api.contoso.com` is an oauth2 API with "Password grant" enabled. The attacker can still create a fake login form targeting its proxy. Then, its server will be able to send a POST request to the API and get the user access token, right? (assuming the attacker has the client secret, but it's another point)

Comment: @KorHosik: But this has nothing to do with CORS. You are talking about a credential phishing attack in this case, i.e. stealing the login data of a user by tricking them into **explicitly** entering the credentials into the attackers site. CORS is not the solution to every possible security problem but has a specific and limited purpose.